# Shift vowels in a linked list to beginning

Tags: linked-list, singly-linked-list

I was solving a problem in which given a linked list of characters , we have to move the vowels to the beginning such that both vowels and consonants are in chronological order. That is in the order in which they appear in original list.

`Input : S->T->A->C->K->O->V->E->R->F->L->O->W`

`Output : A->O->E->O->S->T->C->K->V->R->F->L->W`

I did it by traversing through the list once and created two lists called vowels and consonants and later merged them.

Can it be done without creating extra lists ? I mean in-place maybe using pointer manipulation?

Comment: Should consonants stay in "chronological order" as well, or can we mix them up?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight chronological order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember the beginning of the list. When you meet a vowel, move it to the beginning of the list; the vowel becomes the new beginning that you remember.

Comment: This is what i had in mind. But was having difficulty in implementing it.

Comment: Show what you've tried. Make sure you know what a linked list is first, and that you can manipulate one.

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Traverse the list
2. When you encounter a vowel, check with head if its smaller or greater
3. If smaller, re-place new vowel before head, else move head and check again
4. In the end relocate head to first

    temp = head;
    while(current.next != null) {
      if(current.isVowel()) {
        if(head.isVowel()) {
          //check the precedence
          //Re-place the current with temp
        }
        else {
          //Re-place current in front of head
        }
      }
      current = current.next;
    }
```

This is an abstract understanding. Implement it properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct list {
    struct list *next;
    int ch;
    };
#define IS_VOWEL(p) strchr("aeiouy", tolower(p->ch))
struct list *shuffle (  struct list *lst )
{
    struct list *new=NULL, **dst, **src;
    dst = &new;
    for (src = &lst; *src; ) {
            struct list *this;
            this= *src;
            if (!IS_VOWEL(this)) { src= &(*src)->next; continue; }
            *src = this->next;
            this->next = *dst;
            *dst = this;
            dst = & (*dst)->next;
            }
    *dst = lst;
    return new;
}

int main (void)
{
    struct list arr[] = { {arr+1, 'S'} , {arr+2, 'T'} , {arr+3, 'A'}
         , {arr+4, 'C'} , {arr+5, 'K'} , {arr+6, 'O'}
         , {arr+7, 'V'} , {arr+8, 'E'} , {arr+9, 'R'}
         , {arr+10, 'F'} , {arr+11, 'L'} , {arr+12, 'O'} , {NULL, 'W'} };
    struct list *result;

    result = shuffle (arr);

    for ( ; result; result = result->next ) {
        printf( "-> %c" , result->ch );
        }
    printf( "\n" );

return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

-> A-> O-> E-> O-> S-> T-> C-> K-> V-> R-> F-> L-> W

Answer (score 0):

You can quite easily modify pointers to create two independent lists without actually having to duplicate any of the nodes, which is what I assume you mean when you say you want to avoid creating new lists. Only the pointers in the original nodes are modified.

First let's create the structures for the list:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Structure for singly linked list.

typedef struct sNode {
    char ch;
    struct sNode *next;
} tNode;
```

And next we provide two utility functions, the first to append a character to the list:

```
// Append to list, not very efficient but debug code anyway.

static tNode *append (tNode *head, char ch) {
    // Allocate new node and populate it.

    tNode *next = malloc (sizeof (tNode));
    if (next == NULL) {
        puts ("Out of memory");
        exit (1);
    }
    next->ch = ch;
    next->next = NULL;

    // First in list, just return it.

    if (head == NULL)
        return next;

    // Else get last, adjust pointer and return head.

    tNode *this = head;
    while (this->next != NULL)
        this = this->next;
    this->next = next;
    return head;
}
```

And the second to dump a list for debugging purposes:

```
// Debug code to dump a list.

static void dump (tNode *this) {
    if (this == NULL)
        return;
    printf ("(%08x)%c", this, this->ch);
    while ((this = this->next) != NULL)
        printf (" -> (%08x)%c", this, this->ch);
    putchar ('\n');
}
```

Beyond that, we need an easy way to tell if a node is a vowel or not. For our purposes, we'll only use uppercase letters:

```
// Check for vowel (uppercase only here).

static int isVowel (tNode *this) {
    char ch = this->ch;
    return (ch == 'A') || (ch == 'E') || (ch == 'I')
        || (ch == 'O') || (ch == 'U');
}
```

Now this is the important bit, the bit that turns the single list into two distinct lists (one vowel, one consonant). Which list is which type depends on what the first entry in the list is.

What is basically does is to create a sub-list out of all the common nodes at the start of the list ("ST" in this case), another sub-list of the next non-matching type ("A"), and then starts processing the remaining nodes one by one, starting with "C".

As each subsequent node is examined, the pointers are adjusted to add it to either the first or second list (again, *without* actually creating new nodes). Once we reach the NULL at then end of the list, we then decide whether to append the second list to the first, or vice versa (vowels have to come first).

The code for all this pointer manipulation is shown below:

```
// Meat of the solution, reorganise the list.

static tNode *regroup (tNode *this) {
    // No reorg on empty list.

    if (this == NULL)
        return this;

    // Find first/last of type 1 (matches head), first of type 2.

    tNode *firstTyp1 = this, *firstTyp2 = this, *lastTyp1 = this, *lastTyp2;
    while ((firstTyp2 != NULL) && (isVowel (firstTyp1) == isVowel (firstTyp2 ))) {
        lastTyp1 = firstTyp2;
        firstTyp2 = firstTyp2->next;
    }

    // No type 2 means only one type, return list as is.

    if (firstTyp2 == NULL)
        return firstTyp1;

    // Type 2 list has one entry, next node after that is for checking.

    lastTyp2 = firstTyp2;
    this = firstTyp2->next;

    //dump (firstTyp1);
    //dump (firstTyp2);
    //putchar ('\n');

    // Process nodes until list is exhausted.

    while (this != NULL) {
        // Adjust pointers to add to correct list.

        if (isVowel (this) == isVowel (lastTyp1)) {
            lastTyp2->next = this->next;
            lastTyp1->next = this;
            lastTyp1 = this;
        } else {
            lastTyp1->next = this->next;
            lastTyp2->next = this;
            lastTyp2 = this;
        }

        // Advance to next node.

        this = this->next;

        //dump (firstTyp1);
        //dump (firstTyp2);
        //putchar ('\n');
    }

    // Attach last of one list to first of the other,
    // depending on which is the vowel list.

    if (isVowel (firstTyp1)) {
        lastTyp1->next = firstTyp2;
        return firstTyp1;
    }

    lastTyp2->next = firstTyp1;
    return firstTyp2;
}
```

And, finally, no complex program would be complete without a test harness of some description, so here it is, something to create and dump the list in its initial form, then reorganise it and dump the result:

```
int main (void) {
    char *str = "STACKOVERFLOW";
    tNode *list = NULL;

    while (*str != '\0')
        list = append (list, *(str++));

    dump (list);
    puts("");

    list = regroup (list);
    dump (list);

    return 0;
}
```

Upon entering, compiling and running all that code, the results are as expected:

```
(09c03008)S -> (09c03018)T -> (09c03028)A -> (09c03038)C ->
(09c03048)K -> (09c03058)O -> (09c03068)V -> (09c03078)E ->
(09c03088)R -> (09c03098)F -> (09c030a8)L -> (09c030b8)O ->
(09c030c8)W

(09c03028)A -> (09c03058)O -> (09c03078)E -> (09c030b8)O ->
(09c03008)S -> (09c03018)T -> (09c03038)C -> (09c03048)K ->
(09c03068)V -> (09c03088)R -> (09c03098)F -> (09c030a8)L ->
(09c030c8)W
```

In case that's hard to read, I'll get rid of the pointers and just list the characters in order:

```
S -> T -> A -> C -> K -> O -> V -> E -> R -> F -> L -> O -> W
A -> O -> E -> O -> S -> T -> C -> K -> V -> R -> F -> L -> W
```